# Custom list with orderby date

Tags: blackberry

i am developing one app in which i need to show list of product by date. so in list there should be appear date first and then product item. now my problem is layout,i am confuse that how can i make this layout?
here is page..

[image]

according to this screen there are date and product detail over there so which changes that i need to change in my code..

Here is my code

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawStyle;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Touchscreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.NullField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.SeparatorField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

class UiMainscreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{
    private CustomListField cu_field[];
    private Bitmap image=null;
    int size=8;
    public UiMainscreen() {
        VerticalFieldManager vmanager=new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
            }
        };
        cu_field=new CustomListField[size]; 
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            image=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("sample_"+i+".jpg");
            cu_field[i]=new CustomListField("BlackBerry models that had a built-in mobile phone, were the first models that natively ran Java, and transmitted data over the normal 2G cellular network. RIM began to advertise these devices as email-capable mobile phones rather than as 2-way pagers.", image, "jan2011", 100, 100,Color.LIGHTGREEN);
            cu_field[i].setChangeListener(this);
            vmanager.add(new SeparatorField());
            vmanager.add(cu_field[i]);
        }
        add(vmanager);
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            if(field==cu_field[i]){
                final int k=i;
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Dialog.alert("You click on Item No "+k);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

class CustomListField extends HorizontalFieldManager{

    private Bitmap scale_image;
    private int width=0;
    private int height=0;
    private int background_color=0;
    private BitmapField bitmap_field;
    private boolean flag=false;
    public CustomListField(String title, Bitmap image, String date,int image_width,int image_height,int background_color){
        super(NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL|USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        this.background_color=background_color;
        width=image_width;
        height=image_width;
        if(image!=null){
            scale_image=new Bitmap(image_width, image_height);
            image.scaleInto(scale_image, Bitmap.FILTER_LANCZOS);
            bitmap_field=new BitmapField(scale_image);
            flag=false;
            bitmap_field.setMargin(5, 5, 5, 5);
            add(bitmap_field);
        }


        VerticalFieldManager vmanager=new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH|Field.FIELD_VCENTER){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth()-width, height);
                setExtent(Display.getWidth()-width, height);
            }
        };
        //HorizontalFieldManager HFMTOPlist  =new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER|Field.FIELD_TOP);
        Bitmap TopStrip = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("logo36X36.png");
        BitmapField bitmapStrip = new BitmapField(TopStrip);
       // HFMTOPlist.add(bitmapStrip);

       // vmanager.add(HFMTOPlist);

        LabelField title_lbl=new LabelField("Title: "+title,Field.NON_FOCUSABLE|DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS);
        vmanager.add(title_lbl);

        LabelField date_lbl=new LabelField("Date: "+date,Field.NON_FOCUSABLE);
        vmanager.add(date_lbl);
        vmanager.add(bitmapStrip);
        Font fon=title_lbl.getFont();
        int title_height=fon.getHeight();

        Font font=date_lbl.getFont();
        int date_height=font.getHeight();
        int pad=title_height+date_height;
        title_lbl.setPadding((height-pad)/2, 0, 0, 0);
        add(vmanager);
        add(new NullField(FOCUSABLE));
    }

    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), height);
        setExtent(Display.getWidth(), height);
    }
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        if(flag)
        graphics.setBackgroundColor(background_color);
        graphics.clear();
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
    protected void onFocus(int direction) {
        super.onFocus(direction);
        flag=true;
        invalidate();
    }
    protected void onUnfocus() {
        invalidate();
        flag=false;
    }
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {

        if(Touchscreen.isSupported()){
            return false;
        }else{
            fieldChangeNotify(1);
            return true;
        }

    }
    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) 
    {
        if (TouchEvent.CLICK == message.getEvent()) 
        {

            FieldChangeListener listener = getChangeListener();
            if (null != listener)
                this.setFocus();
                listener.fieldChanged(this, 1);
        }
        return super.touchEvent(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout is a combination of (`LabelField` + `ListField`) pairs. Implement a list of lists as your data model and implement a `Comparator` instance to sort data in your list of lists according to your rules.

Then compose a screen via adding `LabelField` and `ListField` instances according to your data model and update these fields when your data model changes.

And please note, posting long source code sheets here does not help to solve the problem. Usually when someone asks for help with code, he does his own investigation and posts a small piece of code (~10 lines) and asks for a particular help with it.